# Show that $\cap_{k\in \mathbb{N}}[-\frac{1}{k},k+1]$ is a closed set

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I know that a subset $M$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is open if it contains a ball about each of it points, and closed it its complement is open.

But how would I show that the set $\cap_{k\in \mathbb{N}}[-\frac{1}{k},k+1]$ in $(\mathbb{R},|.|)$ is closed and not open?

Comment: Do you know in generality that the intersection of closed sets is closed?

Comment: The set has a much simpler description.  Ask yourself: Which positive numbers are in the set?  Which negative numbers are in the set?  Is $0$ in the set?  abatkai raises a good point, but in this case it is useful to have a more concrete description first.

Comment: Identify in a picture the intervals $[-1/k,k+1]$ for $k=1$, $2$, $3$, $4$. Find the intersection of these.

Comment: I was again too quick. @JonasMeyer is right.

Comment: Is the set between $[0,2]$?

Comment: Yes, it’s $[0,2]$.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry Im still a bit new to open/closed sets, so how would I proceed with then knowing that the set is between $[0,2]$?

Comment: The set is $[0,2]$, a closed interval. Closed intervals are closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C = \cap_{k\in \mathbb{N}}[-\frac{1}{k},k+1]$, and suppose $x \notin C$. Then $\exists k$, such that $x \notin [-\frac{1}{k},k+1]$. Choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2} \min \{ |x+\frac{1}{k}|, |x-(k+1)|\}$. Then $B(x,\epsilon) \cap C = \emptyset$, since $C \subset [-\frac{1}{k},k+1]$.

Comment: OK, so it is a little brute force :-).

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat The only question is, how did you choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2} \min \{ |x+\frac{1}{k}|, |x-(k+1)|\}$? Is that a standard way to choose epsilon?

Comment: Well, there is no standard way. In the above, either $x < -\frac{1}{k}$, or $x > k+1$. I just choose $\epsilon$ so it would be half the minimum distance from $x$ to the interval. Any other fraction would do, as indeed would many other schemes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!